# Drone.IO - Using GitLab in SSH mode

Tags: ssh, gitlab, drone.io

We would like to disable http access on our GitLab instance and use SSH only. Can drone somehow communicate with GitLab over SSH?

Answer (score 0):

The default clone plugin uses git+https to clone repositories. If you would like to change the default behavior and use git+ssh, you will have to create a custom clone plugin.

```
clone:
  custom:
    image: amazia/custom-git-plugin
pipeline:
  build:
    image: golang
    commands:
      - go build
      - go test
```

The above example demonstrates a yaml configuration that overrides the default clone step to use a custom plugin. Here are some resources for creating custom plugins:

1. http://docs.drone.io/creating-custom-plugins-bash/
2. http://docs.drone.io/creating-custom-plugins-golang/